# Unable to hide links based on security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to show links only if the user role is permitted. 
But the links are not hidden and everything is shown for any roles.

Seen so many similar queries here and none of the solution is working. Please advice what I'm missing.

Configs.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private final String USER = "USER";
    private final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/closed").hasRole(ADMIN).and()
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("jane").password(passwordEncoder().encode("qwe")).roles(ADMIN, USER).and()
                .withUser("john").password(passwordEncoder().encode("qwe")).roles(USER);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

HTML

```
<a th:href="@{/closed}">Go to closed</a>

<br/><br/>

<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out">
</form>

<br/>

<h2>Welcome</h2>
<p>Spring Security Thymeleaf</p>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">Text visible to user.</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">Text visible to admin.</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    Text visible only to authenticated users.
</div>
Authenticated username:
<div sec:authentication="name"></div>
Authenticated user roles:
<div sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></div>
```

Everything above is displayed for Jane even though she has no admin access. Plus even her roles and username is not displayed either.

I also tried configuring the dialect as follows which makes no difference.

```
@Configuration
public class LeafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
}
```

The following is whats displayed for Jane or John., No difference:

```
Welcome
Spring Security Thymeleaf

Text visible to user.
Text visible to admin.
Text visible only to authenticated users.
Authenticated username:
Authenticated user roles:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Security extras, you could instead of `sec:authorization` try using `${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')'}`. For example.

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''USER'')'}">Text visible to user.</div>
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')'}">Text visible to admin.</div>
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
    Text visible only to authenticated users.
</div>
```

In case you use authorities instead of roles, the following code will do the trick.

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''ADMIN'')')}">ADMIN</div>
     <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''USER'')')}">USER</div>
     <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
         Text visible only to authenticated users.
     </div>
</div>
```

Regarding your con figuration, change your `org.thymeleaf.extras` for `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` in your `.pom` and you need to add the Spring Dialect @Bean to your configuration.

**POM**

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

**LeafConfig**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;

@Configuration
public class LeafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

}
```

After these changes, everything should work as intended.

Comment: Tried above, adjusted the '' marks. Still same, non Admin user able to see ADMIN  text.

Comment: Those are not “, but double simple quotes. The other ones worked?

Comment: Also, are you using roles or authorities?

Comment: Tried roles and authorities. Same results. For your answer, if I use it as it is without changing the '' marks, it throws an error. Am I missing something. It looked like a syntax issue to me. Should I use your solution as it is? IDE seems to complain too. Screenshot for ref -> https://imgur.com/a/gIDIByI

Comment: Yeah, you should use it as is. In fact, I just tried on my project and it is working fine. In my case though I use it with authorities. I will update it to also use it with authorities.

Comment: By the way I just realized I missed some ' on the first example. I just edited it.

Comment: I get an error when I add your code to my page. I added the project which is just a couple of files to github if you would like to have a look. Thanks. -> https://github.com/karvai1/check

Comment: Perfect! Works.

Comment: Glad I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like below:

```html
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
  <div>
    This content will only be visible to users who have
    the "ADMIN" authority in their list of GrantedAuthority's.
  </div>
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: The above doesn't work make a difference. John who is not an ADMIN can see it.

Comment: the content inside the access tag will only be seen by users who has one of their role as Admin. Did you try it?

Comment: To clarify, the issue is not about not being unable to see the hidden text. Issue is that I can see the text irregardless of the role. So both ADMIN and USER able to see the text which is incorrect.